# Adding web reference is not generating the expected reference.cs file. Absent functions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005, web-reference

I'm working with an old windows app in visual studio 2005. A webserviced referenced in the original app has 2 functions and when i peak inside the auto-generated reference.cs file I notice a couple of other functions to allow async calls have been geenrated i.e. *Begin*WhateverFunctionNameIsCalled and *End*WhateverFunctionNameIsCalled.

My problem is that I've created a new windows app and added the same web references but the Begin and End functions are not generated in my reference.cs proxy class. Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is VS2005, and isn't generating the async methods. OK; is it .NET 2.0 or .NET 3.0 (via the VS2005/WCF add-on)?. It *looks* like "wsdl.exe" (the original) will generate "FooAsync" methods, but WCF ("scvutil.exe") may generate the "BeginFoo" pattern. You might also look to see if you have used WSE*, for example, "wsewsdl2.exe" or "wsewsdl3.exe".

My bets would be of the WCF version. Note also that different frameworks (Silverlight etc) have their *own* proxy generation classes.

Comment: Really I want wsdl.exe to generate the proxy class so how can I force that to happen? thanks Marc

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to check wsdl file returned by web service if those methods are still available on the server.